# How to test pointer-events: none with Protractor and Jasmine?

Tags: css, testing, jasmine, protractor

Under certain circumstances I am setting the css property "pointer-events:none" to avoid an element being clickable (it is a complex element which cannot be disabled one by one and which it is wrapped by a div and this div has the pointer-events to none)

So what used to be clickable and tested like that, it is not anymore.

When I try to test it I always get this:

```
 Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (167, 407). Other element would receive the click:...
```

Which is expected because as the element is not clickable, the parent element gets the click.

My question is, how to test with Protractor/Jasmine an element which is not clickable by setting this property (pointer-events)?

By the way, the commonly used methods isEnabled and isDisplayed, both of them return true.

I also thought about creating a test which expected the error (although I would prefer a cleaner solution), with toThrow() or ToThrowError() but it didn't work at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try special EC for this - 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable

Example:

```
var isClickable = protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable($('your element here'));
expect(isClickable()).toBeFalsy('Element expected not to be clickable');
```

I met the same problem - how i do assertion that i cannot click on element -

```
myElement.click().then(
  () => {
    fail("Element should not be clickable for Observer");
  },
  (err) => {
    expect(err.message.toString()).toMatch("Element is not clickable at point");
});
```

Putting error callback and asserting that correct error was thrown.

Comment: Use of elementToBeSelected() worked for me instead of elementToBeClickable() which returned true instead of false